# How to add a string to a list of lists

Tags: list, f#, append

I'm new at F# :)

I have `a =[[|"hi"|];[|"how";"are"|];[|"you"|];[|"fine";"and";"you"|]]`

and i would like to add a value like this:

`b = [[|"12345";"hi"|];[|"32443";"how";"are"|];[|"32422";"you"|];[|"23232";"fine";"and";"you"|]]`

those numerical string values comes from a string list

`c = (["12345";"32443";"32422";23232])`

Both a and b have the same length. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, you don't have a list of lists. You have a list of arrays. [|element|] is an array, whereas [element] is a list. And welcome to the inspiring world of F#, hope you'll enjoy the language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `List.map2` function, which takes your 2 lists `a` and `c`, and runs a function for each pair of elements from a and c:

```
let b = List.map2 (fun number array -> Array.append [|number|] array) c a
```

Note that `Array.append` will create new arrays. If the elements of `a` don't have to be an array, but can be a list instead, it will be more efficient. This is because adding an element first in a list is a very fast operation, and it will not create new lists:

```
let a = [["hi"];["how";"are"];["you"];["fine";"and";"you"]]
let b = List.map2 (fun number ls -> number::ls) c a
```

Comment: +1: Interestingly, I don't remember ever seeing `map2` in the wild. Usually I'd see a `zip` followed by a `map` on the list of tuples.

Comment: I haven't used map2 myself either, but I often use zip.

Comment: Thanks! that worked a lot! now, the thing is that i've got an array of arrays (lets call it B),containing elements with different lenghts, and i need to compare B to a List of elements (A). So I have to compare each element of B if it does have any element of A, and if it does, to get me the first data of the array that contains the data. for example: 
`A=[[|"1";"dog";"bird";"frog"|];[|"2";"cat";"snake";"owl";"rabbit"|];[|"3";"frog";"pidgeon"|]..]` 
and `B=["bird";"owl"]` so I this should get `C=[[|"1";"2"|]]`

Thanks a lot! really appreciated

Comment: From your description, it seems that you might be better off with a tuple of (int * string[]), so that `A=[(1, [|"dog";"bird";"frog"|]);(2, [|"cat";"snake";"owl";"rabbit"|])..]`. BTW, note the difference between arrays and lists: [1;2] is a list, but [|1;2|] is an array, so what you have is a list of arrays, not an array of arrays.

Comment: Ok thanks, but my only issue is that i dont know how to change my list of arrays to a tuple, because it has diferent dimensions in every element, how can i do this? Thank you

Comment: Going back to your original question, if `c` would be a list if ints instead of strings, `c = [12345; 32443; 32422; 23232]`, then you could create your tuples with `let b = List.zip c a`.